# Recurring Proposal on Substrate Frontend

Tags: polkadot-js, transactions, substrate-front-end, pallet-treasury

So from polkadot js (UI) while creating treasury proposal and want to make it recurring per cycle, you do you achieve that? Say set the segment input in the picture attached to any positive integer, the proposal will reoccur for that number of time per cycle[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of behavior is not available from the Treasury Pallet directly, but is something you could create using the Scheduler Pallet.

On Kusama and Polkadot, the Scheduler is only accessible by governance, so to start, you would need to open a new Democracy proposal that looks like this:

[image]

You can see in this example, I have scheduled a **periodic** call, which will trigger every 1000 blocks a total of 10 times.

That periodic call will be the treasury proposal you have in mind.

Now this does not seem like a smart thing to do here, since this will simply trigger a new proposal, which will need to be approved and all that again.

Instead, you may want to open something like a [Bounty](https://medium.com/polkadot-network/introducing-bounties-ahoy-d6aa18dce92b), where you can allocate all the funds needed up front, and the bounty curator can deliver payments on a regular schedule for work completed.

But in general, for scheduling repeating tasks, the Scheduler Pallet is what you are looking for.